# TreeView remove nodes with same properties

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I want to cleanup my custom TreeNode with duplicate custom property when i click on button in win forms application.

For Example I have TreeNodes like this,

```
public class CustomFruitCrateNode : System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode
{
    public string FruitName { get; set; }
    public bool EatAble{ get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to cleanup treeview to remove all duplicate nodes with same FruitName and keep only one.

Comment: Why negative vote :-( ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that it two steps. First step - get list of all nodes from TreeView, i.e. flatten TreeView:

```
private IEnumerable<TreeNode> Flatten(TreeView treeView)
{
    Queue<TreeNode> nodes = new Queue<TreeNode>();
    foreach (TreeNode node in treeView.Nodes)
        nodes.Enqueue(node);

    while (nodes.Any())
    {
        var current = nodes.Dequeue();
        foreach (TreeNode subNode in current.Nodes)
            nodes.Enqueue(subNode);
        yield return current;
    }
}
```

And second step - group nodes and remove from each group all nodes except first one:

```
Flatten(treeView1)
    .Cast<CustomFruitCrateNode>()
    .GroupBy(n => n.FruitName)
    .SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(n => n.Remove());
```

Comment: @CustomizedName keep in mind, that your approach will work only if there is not more than two levels in tree view

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did then,

```
 private void bCleanUpTreeView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> vDic = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (CustomFruitCrateNode node in treeView1.Nodes)
        {
            foreach (CustomFruitCrateNode childNode in node.Nodes)
            {
                if (!vDic.ContainsKey(childNode.FruitName))
                {
                    vdDic.Add(childNode.Location, childNode.FruitName);
                }
                else
                {
                    childNode.Remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```